# Get Parent_ID by list of Child_Id in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a mapping table of Parent_Node and Child_Node- **Parent_Child**

A **PARENT** can have multiple **CHILDs**, and a **CHILD** can be a part of multiple **PARENTs**.

```
create table Parent_Child(Parent_Id int,Child_Id int);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 219,217);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 219,218);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 221,172);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 221,217);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 221,218);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 222,47);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 222,172);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 222,217);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 222,218);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 223,47);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 223,160);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 223,172);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 223,217);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 223,218);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 226,47);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 226,160);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 226,172);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 226,217);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 226,218);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 226,224);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 226,225);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 227,218);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 227,224);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 227,225);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 228,218);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 228,225);
```

I need to find a **PARENT**, having only the list of specific **CHILDs**.
Such as,

> INPUT (CHILD_ID) = 217, 218 ||
> EXPECTED OUTPUT = PARENT_ID- 219

Could anyone help in getting the correct SQL? Tried with below SQL, but didn't worked--

```
    SELECT * from Parent_child_rltnp
        group by PARENT_ID
        having count(DISTINCT CHILD_ID) = 2 AND CHILD_ID IN (217, 218);
```

it fetched me two records of PARENT_IDs- 219, 228
instead of returning only one PARENT_ID- 219(having exact match of CHILD_Ids)

---

We are using MYSQL v5.7

Comment: Multiple students asking the same homework question...

Answer (score 1):

Below you will find 3 different alternatives giving the same expected result

Alternative I.

```
SELECT Parent_Id
FROM Parent_Child 
GROUP BY Parent_Id
HAVING MIN(Child_Id) = 217
   AND MAX(Child_Id) = 218;
```

Alternative II.

```
SELECT Parent_Id
FROM Parent_Child
GROUP BY Parent_Id
HAVING SUM(Child_Id in (217,218)) = COUNT(*);
```

Alternative III

```
SELECT Parent_Id
FROM Parent_Child 
GROUP BY  Parent_Id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Child_Id order by Child_Id asc ) ='217,218';
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/6DQ1I_3k)

[Reference](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/313625/select-only-rows-where-all-values-in-a-column-match-a-value-for-an-id)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table Parent_Child(Parent_Id int,Child_Id int);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 219,217);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 219,218);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 221,172);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 221,217);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 221,218);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 222,47);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 222,172);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 222,217);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 222,218);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 223,47);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 223,160);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 223,172);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 223,217);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 223,218);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 226,47);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 226,160);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 226,172);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 226,217);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 226,218);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 226,224);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 226,225);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 227,218);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 227,224);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 227,225);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 228,218);
INSERT INTO Parent_Child VALUES( 228,225);
```

Query:

```
SELECT Parent_Id ,count(*) child_count,count(case when child_id in (217,218) then 1 end )input_child_count  from Parent_Child
group by Parent_id
having child_count=input_child_Count
```

Output:

| Parent_Id | child_count | input_child_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 219 | 2 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qBKWgXPH)

Comment: No, it didn't work

Comment: It returns student_id 2. Please let me know your desired answer if it's not.

Comment: I checked with the above-mentioned data in your fiddle - https://dbfiddle.uk/Q9ghHjWr 
The execution failed

Comment: @AKR040322 but it's returning 2 while I am checking. Would you please check again. Sometimes it can fail for fiddle's internal reason.

Comment: Please share the error message.

Comment: I ran the query -- [SELECT Parent_Id from Parent_Child where Child_Id IN (217,218) group by Parent_Id having count(DISTINCT Child_Id) = 2;]

Got following Parent_Ids-
219,221,222,223,226 instead of just 219

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur in fact, this is wrong because you should use `where COURSE_ID IN (102,103)` because automatically you are filtering out other values and in the having you are testing only for this two particular values

Comment: @ErgestBasha you are absolutely right. Missed that. I have changed my answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AKR040322 I have changed my answer. Please check.